# Asp.Net Bootstrap Classes On <asp:DropDownList

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>
Account Group - Add - My ASP.NET Application
</title><script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./groupAdd" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"    value="tRJn2Kjwvz2Puav8tcpz3Ls6wGBUmb5Ja174Y3bdllDemDMYow1wPnjeUZgjA1y+av/mqygIOqBBxlrkr1A6axhfG/Ic4fMYi6poCOfltc5MR88HYxVigJJBG3tIvHfroT0iXc0csFM0mwyzWlNttzAhjZx7Xogq99vurKroKnK4q23wfM8J72YgScmhpcujEBgtDuKzbt8o6nu6VjwNYg==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
       theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<script src="/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bundles/WebFormsJs?v=AAyiAYwMfvmwjNSBfIMrBAqfU5exDukMVhrRuZ-  PDU01" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ctl08', 'ctl01', [], [],    [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="MainContent_eGroupCode" id="MainContent_lGroupCode">Group Code</label>
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$eGroupCode" type="text" maxlength="10" id="MainContent_eGroupCode" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="MainContent_ddGroupType" id="MainContent_lGroupType">Group Type</label>
            <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddGroupType" id="MainContent_ddGroupType" class="form-control">
<option value="IN">Incomes</option>
<option value="EX">Expenses</option>
<option value="AS">Assets</option>
<option value="LI">Liabilities</option>

</select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="MainContent_eGroupName" id="MainContent_lGroupName">Group Name</label>
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$eGroupName" type="text" maxlength="40" id="MainContent_eGroupName" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$bSave" value="Save" id="MainContent_bSave" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - PFA</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="3AAE92F6" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="qSAzVSuS/WkdQ0+7cpffhRi71ZlGYos9x6mRfTlJETXx5PzLHrvJMrvKTBR+gk0eqMw6L0G8IaFchRCu2+y5qUSvQESXisN7B0rrXdNd3EB6D+zzcccmRVsiGszQD39higpryIq2R7q+im2eg0bLsdGa55i5eD7cOF8/Kh9ZNlMhO8NUTJ05Ef8LDMxYv+jB89mlh5Un6dkvjksggF8mBZp2pDYrDoGaINzbFwJzC5Q65UIgChzA9VRKUUWFG/BU" />
</div></form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
{"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"d3ed4f11e0994099a89d07a103267276"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:50950/1ed6bd9582884a84ad84c822a4bf5589/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!--  End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>



   Version 2
   <%@ Page Title="Account Group - Add" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="groupAdd.aspx.vb" Inherits="PFA.groupAdd" %>
   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lGroupCode" Text="Group Code" AssociatedControlID="eGroupCode"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eGroupCode" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lGroupType" Text="Group Type" AssociatedControlID="ddGroupType"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddGroupType" CssClass="form-control">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Incomes" Value="IN"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Expenses" Value="EX"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Assets" Value="AS"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Liabilities" Value="LI"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lGroupName" Text="Group Name" AssociatedControlID="eGroupName"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eGroupName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result - the dropdown is still wider than the text boxes above and below.

[image]

---

Please see screenshot of rendered for below. Why does the dropdownlist occupy the whole screen width while the other two controls don't? Very new to web development. Please advice and help. Many thanks. Iyer

```
<%@ Page Title="Account Group - Add" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="groupAdd.aspx.vb" Inherits="PFA.groupAdd" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lGroupCode" Text="Group Code" AssociatedControlID="eGroupCode"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eGroupCode" CssClass="form-control">    </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lGroupType" Text="Group Type" AssociatedControlID="ddGroupType"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddGroupType" CssClass="form-control" width="100%">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Incomes" Value="IN"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Expenses" Value="EX"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Assets" Value="AS"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Liabilities" Value="LI"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lGroupName" Text="Group Name" AssociatedControlID="eGroupName"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="eGroupName" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

[image: Screenshot of rendered form]

Comment: because you have given the `width:100%` fro thr drodownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Webruster says, you have specified a width of 100%. However, that's not the whole story. Even without this, Bootstrap will by default define a CSS width of 100%. Try wrapping the whole block in a `<div class="col-***">` tag to better control sizes. For example, `col-sm-3`.

See the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) for how to control form sizes.

**EDIT:**
After chatting with the OP for a while, it transpired that the problem is with the `Content/Site.css` file that's automatically generated by Visual Studio when creating a new Web Forms app. Amongst other things, it contains the following style:

```
/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */ 
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"], 
input[type="email"], 
input[type="tel"], 
input[type="select"]{ 
max-width: 280px; 
}
```

This is overriding the default Bootstrap behavior. Furthermore, there is not (as far as I'm aware) an input type called `select`. Asp.net dropdown lists render to normal `select` tags. So what the above style does is restrict the maximum width of several `input` tags, without affecting the dropdown lists.

There are two solutions. First, we can simply delete this block entirely. This will allow Bootstrap to behave as expected, as far as form elements are concerned. This would be my preference.

Second, replace `input[type="select"]` with simply `select`. If it transpires that my knowledge of input types is lacking, then add "`, select`" after it, rather than replacing it (don't forget the comma!)

Comment: Thanks - had done that initially but that did not help so, tried this - without the 100% width as well - let me change and post it back.

Comment: If you're having trouble, you may need to create another outer `<div class="row">`, and nest it inside that. The column classes represent some division of 12 at a particular screen size. For example, `<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-sm-3">....</div></div>` will take up 3/12 (1/4) of the width of the parent row at small screen sizes and above (unless a larger size is also specified).

Comment: Even that does not help.

Comment: No change if I add Width="100%" to the textboxes. Their sizes do not change. Thanks

Comment: Could it be asp.net? Am editing my question and pasting view source

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap extensively with asp.net with no issues, but it's possible there might be something outside the specific page code shown that's affecting it I guess...

Comment: Does the `form` tag on your master page have a class applied to it, like `form-inline` or similar?

Comment: No, the form has no class applied - just runat="server"

Comment: Bootstrap version is 3.0.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124803/discussion-between-k-y-iyer-and-michael-mcmullin).